# All configuration files are embedded in jars?

Tags: configuration, java

What does it mean that

> All configuration files are embedded in jars.

for the [Apache Jakarta James e-mail server](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html)?

Does that mean that config files must be placed back into the JAR file?  Or, can they live in the conf directory?

Answer (score 1):

The link you give says:

> - All configuration files are embedded in jars.
> - We ship in the conf folder template configuration files.
> - You can override the default configuration : 
>       Copy the conf folder any ...-template... you need and update according to your needs.

The last part isn't particularly clear, but as I understand it, it means you can copy any template file to the `conf` folder, giving it the appropriate name, and use that to override the configuration which is embedded in the JARs. You shouldn't place your own configuration in the JAR files, just leave it in the `conf` directory.